# python bob.core installation error : couldn't find boost's version.hpp

Tags: python, boost, debian, python-bob

I'm trying to install bob.core python module using pip install bob.core.
But it terminates with the following traceback :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-ljlw6d/bob.core/setup.py", line 46, in <module>
        boost_modules = ['system']
      File "/project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bob/blitz/extension.py", line 52, in __init__
        BobExtension.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
      File "/project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bob/extension/__init__.py", line 356, in __init__
        boost_pkg = boost(boost_req.replace('boost', '').strip())
      File "/project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bob/extension/boost.py", line 69, in __init__
        raise RuntimeError("could not find boost's `version.hpp' - have you installed Boost on this machine?")
    RuntimeError: could not find boost's `version.hpp' - have you installed Boost on this machine?
```

Boost resides in /usr/ of my file system...

Please suggest a solution.